# Definite Integral of Trigonometric Functions

Tags: calculus, integration

I've calculated this to the best of my ability, but I haven't been able to solve it, any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the problem.

[image: http://imgur.com/FVE9aOy]

Here it is as text.

> $$I = \int_0^{\pi/12}\tan^{10}(2x)\sec(2x)dx$$
>    Use partial integration to express the value of
>   $$\int_0^{\pi/12}\tan^{12}(2x)\sec(2x)dx$$
>   in terms of $I$.
>   $$\int_0^{\pi/12}\tan^{12}(2x)\sec(2x)dx = ?$$

I've gotten this far, however I have no idea how to finish it off

[image: http://imgur.com/MoJ9lL0]

Here is my work as text:

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/12}\tan^{12}(2x)\sec(2x)dx = 
\qquad T &= \tan(2x)\\
S &= \sec(2x)\\
J &= \int_0^{\pi/12}T^{12}Sdx
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
J &= \int_0^{\pi/12}T^{11}STdx\\
  &= \frac{1}{2}T^{11}S|_0^{\pi/12} - \frac{11}{\cancel2}\int_0^{\pi/12}T^{10} \times S^2 \times \cancel2 \times Sdx\\
&= \frac{1}{2}T^{11}S|_0^{\pi/12} - 11\int_0^{\pi/12}T^{12}Sdx - 11\int_0^{\pi/12}T^{10}Sdx\\
\end{align}

Note:
$$\int STdx = \frac{1}{2}S+C$$
$$S^2 = T^2+1$$
$$T'=S^2 \times 2$$

Comment: it would increase your chance to get an answer if you post the formulae here as text.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. :(

Comment: @Francis Hold on, I'll format it for you.

Comment: for next time cf http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Thank you zenohm for your help.

Comment: @Francis Check through my translation of your work and tell me if there's anything wrong.

Comment: your answer is fine. I was kind of blind.